# Orthogonal matrix multiplication by orthonormal matrix???

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

$a=6b_1-2b_2+3b_3$ vector given in orthonormal basis $\{b_i\} $where $i=1,2,3$

Orthogonal tensor : 
$Q=cosθb_1⊗b_1+sinθb_1⊗b_2-sinθb_2⊗b_1+cosθb_2⊗b_2+b_3⊗b_3$

Can you tell me how to matrix representation Qa?

Thank you...

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Always glad to see a new face :D However, what have you tried concerning this problem? What do you know that you think might help you here? What is the context? Why do you need help with the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us take some examples

$$b_1\otimes b_1=\pmatrix{1\\0\\0} \pmatrix{1&0&0}=\pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0}$$

$$b_1\otimes b_2=\pmatrix{1\\0\\0}\pmatrix{0&1&0}=\pmatrix{0&1&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0}$$

$$b_2\otimes b_1=\pmatrix{0\\1\\0}\pmatrix{1&0&0}=\pmatrix{0&0&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&0}$$

etc...

Thus, gathering all these contributions:

$$Q=\pmatrix{\cos(\theta)&0&0\\ 0&0&0\\0&0&0}+\pmatrix{0&\sin(\theta)&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0}+\cdots =  \pmatrix{\  \ \cos(\theta)&\sin(\theta)&0\\ -\sin(\theta)&\cos(\theta)&0\\0&0&1}$$

Interpretation: it is a rotation matrix with angle $-\theta$ around the $z$-axis.

Thus, with $A=\pmatrix{6\\-2\\3}$,

$$QA=\pmatrix{\  \ \cos(\theta)&\sin(\theta)&0\\ -\sin(\theta)&\cos(\theta)&0\\0&0&1}\pmatrix{6\\-2\\3}=\pmatrix{6\cos(\theta)-2\sin(\theta)\\-6\sin(\theta)-2\cos(\theta)\\3}$$

Comment: Thank you but this is the representation of orthogonal tensor Q. There is also a vector in orthonormal basis a. I need  Qa?

Comment: I add a preliminary explanation.

Comment: Is there a reason why you have un-validated my answer ? Something wrong with it ?

Comment: No I appreciate it. But your answer shows only the presentation of tensor Q. Can you please tell me the solution steps of Qa? Or is it the same thing? I did not get it.

Comment: I will check it now. Even so can you explain me Qa?

Comment: I have added the answer about $QA$.